# Bash - Catch input for a substituted command stored in variable

Tags: bash, command, variable, input

How would I be able to catch the input for a substituted command stored in a variable?

#### Example:

How would I be able to catch the input for the following command?

```
bar_foo=$(openssl passwd -1 -salt "foobar")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you're showing above would catch the output from the subcommand, ie. `$(...)` into your variable, `$bar_foo`. When using `openssl` you can provide the password using either the `-in` or the `-stdin` switches.

#### Example

```
$ myvar=$(openssl passwd -1 -salt "foobar" -stdin <<< "blah")
$ echo $myvar
$1$foobar$1ips4/cyJvjUjCj8w4exx0
```

It's generally advisable to put the password in a file and then call `openssl`, since that'll keep it out of your history and shield it from being exposed too openly.

#### UPDATE #1

The OP ended up using this method to prompt the user for their password using `read` and then storing it in a variable, `pass1`.

```
$ read -p "Password: " -s pass1
```

This variable could then be used as input to the `openssl` command.

```
$ myvar=$(openssl passwd -1 -salt "foobar" -stdin <<< "$pass1")
$ echo $myvar
$1$foobar$1ips4/cyJvjUjCj8w4exx0
```